# XSLT 2.0: Check if string within a node-set is contained in another string

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslkey

I have a requirement in which the input XML that is received has different error description for the same error code. I need to compare whether a part of the text is contained within the error description in order to do some filtering. Below is the snippet of what I am trying to do.

Created a variable to store a list of all the partial text to be checked within the error description.

```
<xsl:variable name="partialTextList">
    <errorDesc value="insufficient funds" />
    <errorDesc value="amount cannot exceed" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Created a key to access the variable

```
<xsl:key name="kErrorDesc" match="errorDesc" use="@value" />
```

The input XML to this XSL will have something like

```
<Error>
    <Code>123</Code>
    <Desc>Transaction cannot be processed as account has insufficient funds.</Desc>
</Error>
```

OR

```
<Error>
    <Code>123</Code>
    <Desc>The withdrawal amount cannot exceed account balance.</Desc>
</Error>
```

Is it possible to use `contains` function to check whether `<Desc>` has one of the values from `partialTextList`?

I tried to look up a solution for this comparison but was not able to find one. Most of the solutions are to check whether `<Desc>` value is present in the list but not vice-versa.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of e.g. `xsl:template match="Error"` you can certainly check `$partialTextList/errorDesc/@value[contains(current()/Desc, .)]` or move it to the pattern `xsl:template match="Error[$partialTextList/errorDesc/@value[contains(current()/Desc, .)]]"` if you like.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the suggestion. I guess I was thinking on totally different lines of using key.